# debugging for a geometric series in python

Tags: python, fold

```
def fold2(op, term, a, next, b, base): 
    if a > b:
        return base
    else:
        return op (term(a), fold2(op, term, next(a), next, b, base))



def geometric_series(a, r, n):
    return fold2(lambda x,y: x+y, lambda x: a*(r**(n-1)), 1, lambda n: n+1, n, a)
```

Can someone help me with this code. It's suppose to give a geometric series but i am only allowed to change the part **def geometric_series(a, r, n)**. What's wrong with it?

a) geometric_series(1/2, 1/2, 3) = 0.875    (correct)

b) geometric_series(1, 2, 4) = 33               (wrong) correct answer is 15

Comment: What is wrong with this program?

Comment: i added in the examples

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake in the second lambda of your code:

```
lambda x: a*(r**(n-1))
```

I think `n` and `x` should actually be the same variable here:

```
lambda t: a*(r**(t-1))
```

In addition to that I changed the third argument of *fold2* from 1 to 2 and everything is working as expected.

Comment: If this answer is correct, please mark it as such ^^

Answer (score 0):

Third argument of fold2 should should have the same variable. Either both n or both x. Also, Your final argument, which is the base case, should be 0

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on, the base should be 0 and not a, if not for your test case there will additional 1.

def geometric_series(a, r, n):
    return fold2(lambda x, y: x+y, lambda n: a*(r**(n-1)), 1, lambda n: n+1, n, 0)